# date within range or not

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to check whether user submitted date is within range or not.

```
<?php
$datesyntx = "/^(19|20)\d\d[\-\/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\-\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/";
$paydate = "2015-03-01";
if (preg_match($datesyntx, $paydate)) {
    if(strtotime($paydate) > strtotime('2015-04-23') && strtotime($paydate) < strtotime('2015-07-23')) {
 }
}
?>
```

It is not working what actually I am trying to get.

Comment: Use PHP built-in class DateTime  to compare dates, it's easier & you won't have to convert dates manually or run them through preg_match

Comment: it's a duplicated question , yes was answered before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates .

Comment: I've answered it with easy way . test it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$paydate   = date('2015-03-01');

$DateBegin = date('2010-01-01');
$DateEnd   = date('2016-01-01');

if (($paydate > $DateBegin) && ($paydate < $DateEnd))
{
  echo "is between";
}
else
{
  echo "not between!";  
}
```

P.S: this question was answered before at stackoverflow: 
[PHP check if date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates)
**EDIT2**: easy way .

Comment: What does `date('2015-03-01')` exactly do?

Comment: it's the requested date from client ( I think) , see the question please .

Comment: Do you know that `date('2015-03-01')` returns `2015-03-01`? So why the need for the `date()` function?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `regex` in this scenario, use simple `DateTime` class to check whether user submitted date is within range or not.you can also use typical `strtotime()` to do this job. But `DateTime` class will be great fun for this.

```
<?php
$userSubmitted = new DateTime("2015-04-01");
$startDate=new DateTime("2014-02-01 20:20:00");
$endDate=new DateTime("2015-04-30 23:50:11");
if ($userSubmitted > $startDate  && $userSubmitted < $endDate)
{
    return true;  #date is within the range of yours
}

return false;  #date not within the range of yours
```