# PHP if between 2 dates

Tags: php, date

I'm working on a plugin, but I can't get it working.

The code below is supposed to do something when the current date is between 2 chosen dates by the user.

So if date is in between 12-01-2016 (`$snow['period_past']`) and tomorrow is 12-03-2016 (`$snow['period_future']`), do something...

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

$snowStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($snow['period_past']));
$snowEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($snow['period_future']));

if (($date > $snowStart) && ($date < $snowEnd)) {
         // do this and that
}
```

The code above works, but it only works between the dates. How can I make it work so it also works when its at the `$snow['period_past']` date and `$snow['period_future']` date?

Sorry for my bad explanation, English is not my native language.

Comment: Use `>=` and `<=`....

Comment: Not not sure exactly what you're trying to do... maybe     >=    <=

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP check if date between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates)

Comment: @jycr753 I'm sorry but this question is not a duplicate, please read my post so you get my point

Comment: @JeremyHarris that's what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (($date >= $snowStart) && ($date <= $snowEnd)) 
{
     // do this and that
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a  `greater than` `>` or `less than` `<` comparison.

To get the condition to meet when the date is equal to `$snow['period_past']` or `$snow['period_future']`, you should have the following comparison in place:

```
if (($date >= $snowStart) && ($date =< $snowEnd)) 
{
   // your code here
}
```