# How to validate start and end datetime of a content in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am working on a news portal in which a news (content) will expire after a specific time.The problem is i have to show only one news at one time, i am not sure how to validate it and check that if there is already a news exist of the same duration in database?

Note user can add future (upcoming) news too. Example is below

```
$newsStartDate = '2017-10-10 14:52:10'; 
$newsEndDate = '2017-10-11 14:53:10';
```

I have 2 datetime type column in database (start,expire) now i have to that weather there is already any news exist in the duration of selected `$newsStartDate`,`$newsEndDate` or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make this comparison in database with `BETWEEN` in your SELECT from database. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE datetime BETWEEN 2017-10-10 14:52:10 AND 2017-10-11 14:53:10;
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM News WHERE start < NOW() AND expire > NOW();
```

But if you want to compare dates in php you could use comparison operators to deal with dates:

```
if ($newsDate > $newsStartDate && $newsDate < $newsEndDate) { }
```

See more here:

> [PHP check if date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates)

Comment: we have 2 values to check and also 2 columns, it won't work, no way.

Comment: In that case, `NOW()` should help:
`SELECT * FROM News WHERE start < NOW() AND expire > NOW();`

Comment: we do no have to compare it with now but with  $newsStartDate and $newsEndDate. Please ready the question.

Comment: Quite a strange decision not to compare it in database. But if you want to do this you could use comparison operators to deal with dates:
`if ($newsDate > $newsStartDate && $newsDate < $newsEndDate) { }`