# How to check if a number is in between two numbers (or dates)?

Tags: php

I get two values from GET

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

These are:

```
1-11-2018
30-11-2018
```

Then I remove the `dash` to create a whole number

```
$start = str_replace(["-", "–"], '', $start);
$end = str_replace(["-", "–"], '', $end);
```

Now we have:

```
1112018
30112018
```

Then we do a loop over our posts (we only have 2 posts) and we grab the value from a custom field:

```
$myDate = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-custom-80', TRUE);
```

Which gives us:

```
13-11-2017
26-11-2018
```

And then we do:

```
$myDate = str_replace(["-", "–"], '', $start);
```

And we have:

```
13112017
26112018
```

So now we can check if the `value` we're getting from the `custom field` is within or not the `values` we have from `GET`

```
if (($myDate >= $start) && ($myDate <= $end)) {
  //content....
```

But I am getting the logic wrong, also because the dates from `GET` could have `1` without a `zero` at the beginning `01` and the number would be less even tho the actual date is correct to be considered within it.

Any idea how I can check if `$myDate` is in between `$start` and `$end`?

**UPDATE**

If I don't remove dash and I get:

```
Start date: 1-11-2018
End date: 30-11-2018 
User date: 13-11-2017
```

And then I simply do:

```
if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) {
```

I get ALL posts and not the filtered by range

Comment: Basically you need to check that your `myDate ` is between the two date `$start` and `$end` right?

Comment: @Curious_MInd exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065661/342740)

Comment: why are you removing the dashes?  call `strtotime()` on all your dates and compare results.

Comment: @rob.m I've added answer for you then :)

Comment: You can follow this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` to parse date then compare dates like below-

```
     $start  = strtotime('1-11-2018');
     $end  = strtotime('30-11-2018');  
     $myDate = strtotime('13-11-2017');
     if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) {
        ......
        // your other code goes here
     }
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks this works

Comment: @rob.m be sure to read the notes on [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) to ensure your dates are always compliant.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this way with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class,

```
<?php
$myDate = new DateTime('26-11-2018'); // 13-11-2017 is not between you can test
$start = new DateTime('1-11-2018');
$end = new DateTime('30-11-2018');

if ($myDate > $start && $myDate < $end ){
  echo "Date is between";
}else{
   echo "Date is not between!";  
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Grv1X

Comment: No need to use `getTimestamp()` DateTimeInterface objects can be compared directly.  https://3v4l.org/mQjBY

Comment: @fyrye ohh my bad.yes you're 100% right thanks :)

Comment: it gives me an error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,` the values of start/end are from GET  `$start = $_GET['start'];`

Comment: I also suggest using [`::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to ensure the [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) is not mishandled

Comment: make sure the $start and $end is string date value. To be sure you can check it using `var_dump($start);`

Comment: I need to convert it into a string date value