# Get difference between 2 dates with unix

Tags: php, unix

Trying to get the difference between last date vs today.

In a json file, i have unix date:

```
      "lastUpdate": 1568937600,
```

And i've tried this but with no success.

```
<?php
$day = $item['lastUpdate'];;
$datetime1 = date_create('$day');
$datetime2 = date_create('now');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates

Comment: how? i dont see how to use .json...

Comment: Take a look on link provided and you will figure out how to calculate time

Comment: If you don't mind to educate me on that, because i am not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $item['lastUpdate'])); //assuming that you have timestamp in the var $item
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("now"))));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: That is time in `Hours` you can format like you wish.

Comment: I does not display the hours, is displaying "H:i:s".

Comment: Difference between days H:i:s .

Answer (score 0):

Your [date_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) call on `$day` is wrong. You need to use double quote to render the variable inside. Also you need an `@` sign prefix to indicate it to be a timestamp:

```php
<?php
$day = (int) $item['lastUpdate'];
$datetime1 = date_create("@{$day}");
$datetime2 = date_create('now');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');
?>
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/504afecb72bab656bcaf3be8d95bf7f06f5be845

Answer (score 0):

`date_create()` receives the date/time string in with one of the specific [Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). In your case, you're trying to convert a Unix Timestamp to a DateTime object. You can do that properly by replacing the following line:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('$day');
```

with:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('@'.$day);
```